# When does python parse code files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I am currently running evaluations with multiple parameter configurations in a medium sized project.

I set certain parameters and change some code parts and run the main file with python.

Since the execution will take several hours, after starting it I make changes to some files (comment out some lines and change parameter) and start it again in a new tmux session.

While doing this, I observed behaviour, where the first execution will use configuration options of the second execution, so it seems like python was not done parsing the code files or maybe lazy loads them.

Therefore I wonder how python loads modules / code files and if changing them after I started the execution will have an impact on the execution?

Comment: Python parses and compiles code when you import the file. It does not reload code once loaded.

Comment: So before the first line of code is executed, the main file does it's imports, then the imported files do their imports, then their imports, etc. - which means that as soon as the first statement after the imports get executed I could 'delete the whole project' since everything is loaded? Does the module cache get invalidated in any other case beside an explicit reload or deleting a module explicitly from the code?

Comment: @MartijnPieters is right, but if you have hidden import (dynamic import) like using `__import__` it may affect the compilation.

Comment: @CarlAmbroselli: The 'module cache' is the in-memory data structures that Python builds on executing module code (living in `sys.modules`). You can delete those (`del sys.modules[modulename]`), which is an explicit invalidation. Bytecode (the result of the compilation, and what Python executes) is cached as `.pyc` files (in Python 3, in the `__pycache__` subdirectories).

Comment: @Mark: that's just deferring the import, it is still an import. `__import__` is used by the `import` statement to do the work.